# Java GUI having two columns layout using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm learning Java GUI and struggling dividing layout.

My current output looks like this

Current Output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ics4m.png]

But I wanna make list view and one button on the left side, and other components on the right side like this

Result Output should be like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsJK.png]

I tried to divide into two columns by adding BorderLayout
For example,

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

//List on the left side
String[] tests = new String[] { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5" };
JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
list.setListData(tests);
list.setSelectionBackground(Color.BLUE);
list.setSelectionForeground(Color.WHITE);
list.setFixedCellWidth(100);
frame.add(list, BorderLayout.WEST);
//List on the left side

//All Components on the right Side
JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
JPanel emailPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email");
JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
JTextField email = new JTextField(10);

namePanel.add(nameLabel);
namePanel.add(name);
emailPanel.add(emailLabel);
emailPanel.add(email);
frame.add(namePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(emailPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);


// CheckBox Panel
JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
JLabel lblHobby = new JLabel("Programming Language:");

// CHECKBOX LIST
JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox("Java");
JCheckBox check2 = new JCheckBox("C++");
JCheckBox check3 = new JCheckBox("C");
JCheckBox check4 = new JCheckBox("Python");
JCheckBox check5 = new JCheckBox("Other");
checkBoxPanel.add(lblHobby);
checkBoxPanel.add(check1);
checkBoxPanel.add(check2);
checkBoxPanel.add(check3);
checkBoxPanel.add(check4);
checkBoxPanel.add(check5);
frame.add(checkBoxPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
// CheckBox Panel

// BUTTON
JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
JButton newButton = new JButton("New");
frame.add(saveButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(newButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
// BUTTON

//Set size, title and visible
frame.setSize(500, 400);
//frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setTitle("Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

What do I need to do in order to make two columns in GUI?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not all your code.  A `BorderLayout` should work so what did you actually do?

Comment: Q: What do I need to do in order to make two columns in [Java Swing] GUI?  A: You need to read up on [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).  Remember, too, that you can add layouts inside of layouts, if you need a more complex structure.  But you definitely need to show us your code before we can help any further.

Comment: Undo you last edit. I just updated your question to display the images. When you update your question, don't use the "back" button on your browser. Click on the "Edit" button to make sure you are editing the most recent version of your question,.

Comment: @markspace just figured out to put an example!

Comment: @camickr Can you do me a favor for that again? I'm not used to this website..

Comment: @paulsm4 Should I make another panel that includes all components on the right side and add it to JFrame, not add each component to JFrame?

Comment: @1547kime  click on the "Editied xx mins ago" link and then rollback the edit. Once the edit is rolled back click on the "edit" link (under the "Java Swing" tags) and then add back in your code.

Comment: @camickr Just edited, thanks!

Comment: @1547kime *I make another panel that includes all components on the right side and add it to JFrame,* - Correct. The default layout manager of the content pane of the frame is the BorderLayout. You can only add 5 components, one to each of the 5 areas. However, a component can be a panel containing any number of components and nested panels. Each nested panel can use a different layout manager as well.

Comment: Note that while this can probably be answered based on the screenshot of the required GUI (see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65138270/418556)), there is still no [mre] as suggested by @markspace in the 1st comment. The code snippet seen above has no imports, class structure or main method, and is therefore *not* an MRE. If you cannot solve this using the outline I provided, I'd highly recommend posting an MRE.

Answer (score 3):

```
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Don't change the layout. The FlowLayout just flows components from one line to another. Try resizing your frame wider and see how the component wrap from line to line.

The default layout manager of the content pane of the frame is the `BorderLayout`. You generally want to keep that unless you have a good reason to change it.

Then you design your GUI into logical panels. Each panel can use a different layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

So maybe you add the JList to the left side of the frame:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<>(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Then you create a panel to be added to the center:

```
JPanel center = new JPanel(...);
center.add(...);
frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So pick a layout manager for the CENTER. Maybe you use a BoxLayout and then you add child panels for each row of components.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd look to layout this GUI:
[image]

Starting from the inside and going out, these layouts would be:

- `GREEN` - `FlowLayout` the middle one from the top, centered, the other two  left aligned.
- `PINK` - a `GridBagLayout`. 2 columns down to `Text field2:`, single column thereafter.
- `RED` - a `BorderLayout` with the list in the `LINE_START`, the fields and `Save` / `New` buttons in the `CENTER`, and the (flow layout with the left aligned) button in the `PAGE_END`.

**While it's likely *possible* to create the entire view with a single grid bag layout, that would not lead to the easy to maintain code which would result from the above 'divide & conquer' approach.**